# Mapping JSON property to C# property automatically

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a some json which I am passing to a C# method which has Guids as the property names as shown below

```
 function sendData() { 
    var Mydata = {
        "answers": {
            "3fe69e7e-d753-4079-963e-e4c7dd8643ea": "some name",
            "084cb0ad-040c-49e5-bc4f-3d369b50cbef": "An alternative therapist",
            "084cb0ad-040c-49e5-bc4f-3d369b50cbef-additional": "n/a",
            "77481c26-796f-4f95-b406-e0aa81c54c09": "No",
            "77481c26-796f-4f95-b406-e0aa81c54c09-additional": "n/a",
            "d2fe04bd-70a5-475e-a908-24e79e449502": "Infection of the urinary system, UTI"
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(Mydata),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/PostData"
    });
}
```

I'm trying to map the properties to a C# object which I have defined like

```
public class Answers{
    [JsonProperty("3fe69e7e-d753-4079-963e-e4c7dd8643ea")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I'm simply trying to write out the values to the console however the name property is always null.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public void PostData(Answers answers) {
        Console.WriteLine(answers.Name);
    }
```

Is it possible to get C# to automatically map the values to the correct properties based on the jsonproperty attribute when passed as a parameter in an ajax call?

### Edit

So it seems on further investigation that the jsonproperty attribute is being ignored. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the Json you are passing, you probably need a DTO structure as follows.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Answers answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answers{
    [JsonProperty("3fe69e7e-d753-4079-963e-e4c7dd8643ea")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried that but it did not work.  It doesnt seem to be able to map the json property to the c# property.  It ignores the attribute

Comment: hope you had changed the parameter type of your method as well (to RootObject, above example)

Comment: Yes i changed the param to rootobject

Comment: I also changed the name of tyhe json object from a guid to a proper name and updated the attribute and it still doesnt work

Comment: may be you could begin by debugging your api via Postman or Fiddler. That will help check your controller independent of your client.